# new line when i display 10 ellipse

Tags: java, processing, graphics2d

I am new in **processing** and **java**, I have some exercise to display *100 ellipses* but the screen size is (900, 600), and I want break *100 in 10 lines* of 10, but I don't know how to break line in processing , I already use translate(https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html),but it doesn't work.

```
  //function
  void draw(){
    smooth();
    noStroke();
    fill(23,43,208,200);// cor azul
    ellipse(posX,posY,12,10);

    noStroke();
    fill(242,76,39);//cor vermelho
    ellipse(posX,posY,12,10);

  }


  for (int i=1; i<ellipses.length; i++)
  {
    for (int j=i; j<ellipses.length; j++)
     {
          if(j%10==0)
          ellipses[i].draw();//calling function
     } 
  }
```

Comment: When you are asking a question you should provide some codes you've tried and also mention which part is not working or what kind of errors you got or what output you expect but you are getting another output or so. Please provide a [MCVE] in order to get sooner and more exact help.

Comment: You want two nested loops, one for lines, one for columns. And inside the inner loop you must compute the center of the next ellipse based on the indexes of the two loops. - What is the problem?

Comment: @mayamar i already try that way of do 2 loops and use 1 conditionals if(i%10==0) print ellipse

Comment: can you please post what you tried?

Comment: @ashleedawg i already edit the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class T15DrawEllipses extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Group group = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(group, 900, 600);

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 10; col++) {
                Ellipse e = new Ellipse();
                e.setCenterX(44 + col * 90);
                e.setCenterY(29 + row * 60);
                e.setRadiusX(45);
                e.setRadiusY(30);
                group.getChildren().add(e);
            }
        }
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

A complete example of 10 rows/columns with ellipses.

Comment: I try the code above but it doesn't work, why I need posX and posY don't want center ellipse,i just display 10 per line

Comment: You have variables posX and posY in your draw()-method. Where do you set them? Normally if you want do draw an ellipse you need the center of the ellipse and two radius-parameter. If you want to draw ten ellipse in a line the center of the ellipse will wander from one side to the other. - The nested loops show you how to split the 100 in 10 row with 10 elements and how to get the index in the array of 100 elements.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am using processing for the first time I don't know if about the library that  you use, I will follow your steps

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do when you have questions like this is to get out a piece of graph paper, and draw out a bunch of examples until you notice a pattern. What is the `X,Y` position of every cirlce you want to draw? What is the X value of the first row, the second row, the third row? What is the Y value of the first column, the second column, the third column?

You should also get into the habit of [breaking your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and taking those pieces on one at a time. For example, instead of trying to draw 100 circles in a grid, why don't you just try to draw 10 circles in a single row? Create a function that draws a row of circles. Then try calling that function multiple times to create your grid of circles.

If you get stuck on a specific step, you can ask a more specific question along with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.